# unable to get the output from /token in web API

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, token, postman

I am trying to generate the Token from the Owin. Below is the code of the Startup.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
        HttpConfiguration configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(configuration);
        appBuilder.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(configuration);
    }
    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };
        appBuilder.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        appBuilder.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());    
    }
```

When i am trying to generate the Token using the PostMan below is teh error what I am recieving. Please let me know what is the issue over here.

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm that Owin is started? If you set a breakpoint in above code, does it get hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry.. There was a code mistake i forgot call my ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder appBuilder) method in Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)